# Cosmos DB - thread safe pattern to allocate an 'available' document to reach request

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

For example if I was building an airline booking system and all of my seats were individual documents in a cosmos container with PartitionKey of the `FlightNumber_DepartureDateTime` e.g. `UAT123_20220605T1100Z` and id of `SeatNumber` eg. `12A`.

A request comes in to allocate a single seat (any seat without a preference).

I want to be able to query the cosmos container for seats where `allocated: false` and allocate the first one to the request by setting `allocated: true`  `allocatedTo:ticketReference`.  But I need to do this in a thread safe way so that no two requests get the same seat.

Does Cosmos DB (SQL API) have a standard pattern to solve this problem?

The solution I thought of was to query a document and then update it by checking its Etag and if another thread got in first then the update would fail.  If it fails then query another document and keep trying until I can successfully update it to claim the seat for this thread.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using transactions. Cosmos DB allows you to write [stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs) that are executed in an atomic transaction, basically serializing concurrent seat reservation operations for you within a logical partition.

Quote from "Benefits of using server-side programming" in the link above:

> Atomic transactions: Azure Cosmos DB database operations that are
> performed within a single stored procedure or a trigger are atomic.
> This atomic functionality lets an application combine related
> operations into a single batch, so that either all of the operations
> succeed or none of them succeed.

Bear in mind though that transactions come with a cost. They limit scalability of those operations. However in your scenario when you partition data per flight and given that those operations are very fast, this might be the preferable and most reliable option.

Comment: @lahsrah Please mark the reply as answered if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar with Service Bus queues, essentially allowing you to queue bookings to be saved, therefore you can do the availability logic before you save the booking guaranteeing no overbookings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).